# Can't able to access data by LINQ query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-4

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Playlist(String ID)
        {
            long playid=Convert.ToInt64(ID);
            var q = from client in Clients
                    join m in db.Playlists on client.ClientId equals m.ClientId
                    join meta in db.ContentMetaDatas on m.PlaylistId equals meta.PlaylistId
                    where m.PlaylistId.Equals(playid)
                    orderby m.PlaylistId descending
                    select new SimpleViewModel
                    {
                        ID = m.PlaylistId,
                        Live = false,
                        Expired = meta.ContentMetaDataExpiryDateTime != null,
                        Details = m.PlaylistShortDescription,
                        ImageUrl = meta.ContentMetaDataImage,
                        Title = m.PlaylistTitle
                    };
            return Json(q.ToPage(p, "ID desc"), JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
        }
```

As shown in the above code of controller I want to fetch data those are returned in JSON data format & used in view.

But As I have to convert the string into long datatype, 
what can I do for getting data. Is there anything wrong in the above code??

Comment: Do you get any error or just no data?

Comment: What is your problem? Did you get exception? or what?

Comment: Try using if(Long.TryParse(Id)) { ... } and change controller action to this: public ActionResult Playlist(String Id)

Comment: I am not getting any Exception, I am just not getting any data